# JQuery / JavaScript Add Query String in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to add a Query String in URL when onclick the anchor tag.

**URL Like:** http://example.me/about/about-me

Below is my code.

```
$(".popup_dir").on('click', function() { 
    var exmp_id = $(this).attr('exmp_id');
    window.location.search = 'exmp_id='+exmp_id;
});
```

My Issue is that, when I click it refresh the page and add querystring. But I do not to refresh the page. I want that `onclick` event it will add / update the Query String Value. That's it.

After onclick event I want this type of URL.

**URL Like:** http://example.me/about/about-me/?exmp_id=7

Any Help will be appreciating.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create url like http://example.me/about/about-me/?exmp_id=7 and store it into variable?

Comment: I do not create any URL. I just go on to URL i.e. example.me/about/about-me/ and then I click on href anchor tag. onclick event, I just need to append parameter in query string.

Comment: In browser url bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.history.pushState` to add a new item to the browser's history and update the URL bar, without causing the page to reload:

```
window.history.pushState({}, "", 'http://example.me/about/about-me/?exmp_id=7');
```

This function takes three parameters:

- `data`: Some structured data, such as settings or content, assigned to the history item.
- `title`: The name of the item in the history drop-down shown by the browser’s back and forward buttons.
- `url`: The URL to this state that should be displayed in the address bar (optional).